# PNG image showing up with white background even though it has a clear background

Tags: image, css, png, facebox

I have a facebox window with a close button that i want to be exactly like on uservoice.com (click the feedback link on the bottom right you'll see what i mean. I have added that image as the close button, but when it appears in my browser it shows a white background. The image is supposed to have a clear background. Any idea how to make it show as transparent?  Here's an image of what i'm talking about: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfxC1.png

Here's the CSS for the close button:

```
    #facebox .close{

  position:absolute;
  top:-22px;
  right:-24px;
  padding:2px;
  background:#fff;
}
#facebox .close img{
  opacity:0.3;
}
#facebox .close:hover img{
  opacity:1.0;
}
```

Comment: please post some css so we can take a look.

Comment: Which browser(s)? Are you 1000% sure it's a proper transparent `.png`? You haven't set `background-color: #fff` on that element, have you?

Comment: Are you sure the image has a transparent background? Also, make sure that the div behind it (if any) is set to transparent as well.

Comment: I'm certain the image is positive. You can find the image at http://widget.uservoice.com/images/clients/widget2/close.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `#facebox .close`, remove `background: #fff`.

That should be all you need to do. <strike>Although, I can't see where you're setting the `background-image`.</strike>

Answer (score 2):

```
#facebox .close{
  position:absolute;
  top:-22px;
  right:-24px;
  padding:2px;
  background:#fff;
}
```

probably the `background:#fff;` here.